# Django add many to many with Big Integer as primay key

Tags: django, postgresql

I have users model with Positive Big integer field as the primary key, and I want to create a many to many relationship with Roles table, the issue is that the pivot table (containing the relationship) is being created with an integer field (user_id), which doesn't allow me to actually store any relationship for users with high ID number.

```
id = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

This is my user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(_("Display Name"), max_length=64, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_("active"), default=True)

    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
```

and this is my Role model:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Check screenshot of DB schema below

[image]

P.S: I tried creating the relationship manually with:

```
roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related", through='UserRoles')
```

and creating the table:

```
class UserRoles(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='id')
```

But that also didn't work.

Comment: Seems to be an open issue https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25012. There are work arounds that involve creating a manual migration to change the column

Comment: I think 3.2 should handle this. Just listened to Talk Python To Me episode 301 (transcript: https://talkpython.fm/episodes/transcript/301/deploying-and-running-django-web-apps-in-2021 - look at timestamp 23:27). Available to dl at https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2021/feb/19/django-32-beta-1-released/

Comment: What about [M2M through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) model?

Comment: thanks guys, will keep an eye for next version.

Comment: @JPG I tried that, same thing, check my end of post.